# Linker error when calling C library from Objective-C on iOS

Tags: c, objective-c, linker, static-libraries

I am trying to integrate some C libraries in my iOS app which is using Objective-C and Swift.

I am calling C functions from Objective-C and below is my Code.

`int outPut =  wsq_encode_mem(&odata, &olen, 0.75, idata, width, height, 8, -1, NULL);`

I have given Header Search Paths for all .h files and Library search path for all my .a files.

When I try to compile my code it is giving me:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>    "_wsq_encode_mem", referenced from:
>        -[SampleMethodCall encode_mem:height:pixels:] in SampleMethodCall.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: My function declaration in .h file is which is a header file of my C static library

` extern int wsq_encode_mem(unsigned char **, int *, const float, unsigned char *,
                 const int, const int, const int, const int, char *);`

Comment: Did you add all these .a files to **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content**?